# Quickly commenting /* selected C# code */ in Visual Studio (not the // whole line)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, comments, keyboard-shortcuts

Visual Studio has a toolbar button/keyboard shortcut/menu item that [comments out **selected lines** of C# code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/04/13/comment-and-uncomment-code-vstipedit0047.aspx) using `//`.

Is there an equivalent that comments out **just the selected code** using `/* ... */`?

e.g.

Given this code

```
string s = "hello";
Console.WriteLine(s + " world");
```

If you select `+ "world"` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then you end up with

```
string s = "hello";
//Console.WriteLine(s + " world");
```

However, I would like

```
string s = "hello";
Console.WriteLine(s /*+ " world"*/);
```

This would be useful for when I am making some experimental and temporary amendements to an existing codebase whilst fixing a few bugs.

Comment: I think it's meant to tell you that /* */ is EV1L!!! (which it's not)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) does that. It costs money - but it is worth it.

It's called "[Block Comment](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Comment_Uncomment_Code.html)".

And the default keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

Comment: And another good thing about ReSharper is that you can increase the speed of your Visual Studio ten times simply by uninstalling it.

Comment: @ssg - I am not sure about that, however ReSharper is quite the memory hog, especially with larger projects. 8GB RAM seems to satisfy it though.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Macro, but that would be reinventing the wheel, and might not justify the means.

Comment: Out of interest, how much work do you think it would be to create a macro to do this?

Comment: Depends on experience. Resharper license would be cheaper if considering UK contact day rate rather than someone who does a macro occasionally and writing it from scratch and then testing it.